# Storing user configuration in PHP Session vs accessing it every time

Tags: php, session, storage

Every user on my site has a settings file hosted on the server. The user can add and delete "items", for which a reference of them is added to the settings list; therefore, it can become quite big if the user has many "items". The specific question is: is it more efficient to store a file in a PHP Session or just access it for every page request.

I thought about using a database instead of a settings file; however, I thought it would be extremely inefficient since there would be one entry per item each user adds. But, would it still be more efficient to use SQL?

**P.S:** "items" are actually applications, but for the sake of not confusing, it was changed.

*If you believe this question is confusing or requires further explanation, please comment!*

Comment: AFAIK PhpBB is using this method

Comment: Do some benchmarking and figure out what the cutover point in efficiency is. At some point, the overhead of doing an SQL query will be different enough from the file scan/locate+load+parse overhead of an external settings file. But only YOU can figure out what that point is.

Comment: @MarcB: thanks for the reply! I will probably go with that! I'm guessing that the more "items" and users I add, the more accurate the results would be, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL by itself is not very efficient, but the storage engine for sorting / filtering / presenting is. On the other hand the session is just a plain file in some kind of storage, meaning:

- Use sessions storage if the data saved there has to be present on each page request, but unnecessary data will only cost you I/O time on RAM and HD.
- Use SQL if you want to slice the data elegantly, but remember that php is actually executing another application through operating system calls.

Answer (score 1):

If the "items" stored per user are just accessed by the owner (ie not shared by other user, joined, etc), you can use a separate SQLite database per user setting.

The only downside may be schema changes, you must handle them programmatically. We've done it and and is highly scalable.

Comment: You mean like having a new SQL database per user?

Comment: Exactly, one SQLite database per user.